# How to use SQL functions UPPER() and LOWER() with JPA query methods

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA Query method that gets rows by a column value like this:

```
findAllByLastNameOrderBySortKeyAsc(String name)
```

But I would like the query to be case insensitive. In SQL I can use the `upper()` function like this

```
select * from table_name where upper(last_name) like '%NAME%' order by sort_key asc
```

but I haven't been able to find any examples or documentation on how I can implement this with named queries.

**Update:**

Although it does not answer the question of how to use `upper()` or `lower()` with named queries, I was able to solve the problem of a case insensitive query by using `IgnoreCase` in the named query as follows:

```
findAllByLastNameIgnoreCaseOrderBySortKeyAsc(String name)
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the *spring-data-jpa* [documention](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), you must use the **IgnoreCase** keyword to be case insensitive.

Your method definition should be like this:

```
findAllByLastNameIgnoreCaseOrderBySortKeyAsc(String name)
```

The resulting SQL will be: **… where UPPER(x.firstame) = UPPER(?1)**

Comment: This information was already posted in the question. If you would like to add more information, such as a link to the relevant documentation, or other alternatives to `upper()` and `lower()` - as not every use case for these functions is case insensitive - then posting an answer would be useful.